# How can recognize user selected which ones?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets, struts

I have two list on my request on jsp. First one is productGroupName, and the second is products.

Now, I show these like below.

```
<html:form action="/priceOrder"> <table width="100%" id="tableStyle" style="font: message-box;padding: 20px;">
        <logic:iterate id="productGroups" name="productGroup">
        <tr>
            <td>
            <h3 style="background-color: #720D00; color: white;"><bean:write
                name="productGroups" property="prodGroupName" /></h3>
            <table width="100%" id="tableStyle" style="font: message-box; color: white; padding: 20px; background: #F15A00;">
                <tr>
                    <td width="200px"><strong>Product Name</strong></td>
                    <td width="100px"><strong>How Many</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Info</strong></td>
                </tr>
                <logic:iterate id="product" name="products">
                <tr>
                    <c:if test="${(productGroups.prodGroupID) == (product.prodGroupID)}">
                        <td>
                            <html:checkbox property="productChecked"  ><bean:write name="product" property="prodName"/></html:checkbox>                                 <br />
                        </td>
                        <td><html:text property="quantity" styleId="check"  size="5"/></td>
                        <td><bean:write name="product" property="prodDesc" /></td>
                    </c:if>
                </tr>
                </logic:iterate>
            </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </logic:iterate>

        <tr align="center" style="background-color: #F15A00;"><td height="50px">
              <html:submit styleId="buton" property="method"><bean:message key="button.order" /></html:submit>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
    </table></html:form>
```

As you see firstly I iterate productGroupNames, showing if productID is equal to productGroupID under productGroupName. But I have a problem on getting check box and quantity info. I need which product is checked and how many that is wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing a form submit directly, submit it through a JS function. In your JS function, since you're iterating your list and giving the checkbox and text field the same name, you'll get an array with the same name.
That is you'll get an array of the IDs. You can get the index of the selected checkbox, get the quantity, get the corresponding list element and populate separate hidden form variables with the value. Then submit it.

An alternative approach would be to have a hidden variable associated with each checkbox which provides some mapping between the list and the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

I don't do Struts, but their documentation at least says that you need the [`<html:multibox>`](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-el/tagreference.html#html:multibox) for this.